# Python lambda sum of a range

Tags: python, function, lambda

I want to write a lambda function which is returning the same result as `sum(range(101))`.

I tried multiple lambda functions but i dont understand how i can implement it.

For example i tried

`f=(lambda x: sum(x), x in range(0,101))`

i tired also `a=x in range(0,101)`
and replace `(lambda x: sum(x))(a)`.

Can you explain/show how i can implement the range and the sum in this example. It would also be great if you explain me why my solution is false because i need to learn this for school and i want to be better. :)

Comment: It's not clear what you want. What you've literally asked for is `lambda: sum(range(101))`, but I doubt that's actually what you want.

Comment: How would you use it ? Why re-implementing something simple that exists ? Use a lambda to create something new, not something that is already here

Comment: It is for school i am not allowed to use commands just expressions. Now i need to implement a lambda function which is returning the sum of the first 100 numbers. Which is 5050. My problem is i dont know how i can iterate over the ```range(101)``` and how to give these numbers the lambda function to get back 5050. The ```sum(range(101))``` is an example for normal code which i want implement in an lambda function.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your own attempts to do this — this isn't a "plz do my homework for me" site.

Comment: You say "i am not allowed to use commands just expressions". But what is a "command"? A statement? A builtin?

Answer (score 1):

Gauss formula:

```
lambda x: (x+1)*(x/2)
```

A math genius (Gauss) figured this one out. It only works for summing numbers in a sequence.

Autorecursion:

```
lambda x: (
    lambda f: lambda *args: f(f, *args))(  # Hint: see "Y combinator".
        lambda recur, accumulator, x: recur(recur, acumulator+x, x-1)
        if x
        else accumulator
    )(accumulator=0, x=x)
```

No "commands" (if that means we can't use builtins) only expressions (not statements).

This seems too hard for a beginner, and it's not the natural way to do it in Python. Recursion generalizes to other operations, but can cause a *stack overflow* in Python if `x` is too large.

Answer (score 0):

For any value of `x`:

```
lambda x: sum(range(x))
```

For only 101:

```
lambda: sum(range(101))
```

As for `(lambda x: sum(x), x in range(0,101))`, your expression is a tuple with the first value as `lambda x: sum(x)`, and the second referencing a variable `x` which doesn't exist in the scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = lambda x : sum(range(1, x))
a(10)
```